# handle Link_to_remote in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to move from rails 2 to 5 but `link_to_remote` is not supported by Rails 5:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Add", 
  :url=>{:action=>'fee_submission',:batch=>@batch,s_id=>@stud_id}
```

In controller:

```
def fee_submission
  # ..some code..
  render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html "fee", :partial => "fees"
end
```

View _fees.html.erb:

```
<html>
  code
</html>
```

How can the above code be implemented in Rails 5?

Answer (score 1):

probably you can use remote: true in parameters option from link_to [here is link for more detail](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

```
<%= link_to "Add", fee_submission_controller_path, remote: true %>
```

Comment: And a tutorial: https://rubyplus.com/articles/4211-Using-Ajax-and-jQuery-in-Rails-5-Apps

Comment: Thank you it not working it not rendering partial page and its looking "def show" in controller

Comment: @HemantDarpal did you add `jquery_ujs` to your `application.js`?

Comment: i added jquery_ujs in application.js "//= require jquery_ujs"

Comment: i changed code like this <%= link_to "Add", fee_submission_finance_path, remote: true %> it showing undefined method  "fee_submission_finance_path" controller name "finance" and method is "fee_submission"